# depending loops with ajax request inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

hi im using jquery to run several ajax request in some loops which built a html table.

how can i make them run in specific order?

i tryed $.when and then but in my case that only seem to work using async: false,

i got 2 main functions

1) Building the ajax request url inside a loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {   
    zeile = split[i];

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "url.php?q=" + zeile,
```

and then drawing the basic table

```
success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.data, function(key, val) {
                p = p + "<td>...</td>"     
                p = p + "<td>...</td>"                
                p = p + "</tr>";
                $("#htmlergebnis").append(p);
```

after all the different request are finished and the complete table is drawn i want to run a second function, which adds now table cells from another data source. therefor it uses a value out of each existing row (drawn by the first loops) as a search value for another request

```
 $(".ergebniszeile" ).each(function(key) {  
    ...

    var str = "url2.php?q=" + zeile;
        $.ajax({
            url: "" + str,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {  
                $("#"+rowid+"").children(".value2").append(data.value2);
```

i also tested .ajaxComplete and .ajaxStop but they seem to work with any ajax request not with a specific group of request inside a loop.

i think the problem is the loops which built the ajax urls. its not ajax requests depending on each other but loops with ajax request inside.

The results look + the corresponding request will be built in this order

```
 <tr><th>loop 1</th><th>loop 1</th><th>loop 1</th><th>loop 2</th><th>loop 2</th><tr>
 <tr><td>request 1</td><td>request 1</td><td>request 1</td><td>request 4</td><td>request 4</td></tr>
 <tr><td>request 1</td><td>request 1</td><td>request 1</td><td>request 5</td><td>request 5</td></tr>
 <tr><td>request 1</td><td>request 1</td><td>request 1</td><td>request 6</td><td>request 6</td></tr>
 <tr><td>request 2</td><td>request 2</td><td>request 2</td><td>request 7</td><td>request 7</td></tr>
 <tr><td>request 2</td><td>request 2</td><td>request 2</td><td>request 8</td><td>request 8</td></tr>
 <tr><td>request 3</td><td>request 3</td><td>request 3</td><td>request 9</td><td>request 9</td></tr>
 <tr><td>request 3</td><td>request 3</td><td>request 3</td><td>request 10</td><td>request 10</td></tr>
```

Comment: Are all of your first requests added to the same table? i.e. do each of them return some `data.data`, which you append to the *same* table? I'm not entirely clear how the second lot of AJAX requests are related to the first... can you perhaps expand on your explanation?

Comment: its all in one table. the first colums are drawn out of the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would not focus on making the requests synchronous (on a specific order), that would only slow you down -unless the returned data was really very very big-, it is good to have parallel requests.

What I would do is decouple the fetching of data (requests) -which can perfectly be done asynchronously- and the actual rendering of the table.

So you could for instance just launch the first request to populate the main bit of the table, and then launch the other requests as you are ready to do so. On the success of these calls, just store the result in an array (together with the key of the request), and when all requests are finished then go through the stored results in order (because the key of the request is also stored) and generate the table then.

By the way, instead of concatenating strings

```
            p = p + "<td>...</td>"     
            p = p + "<td>...</td>"                
            p = p + "</tr>";
```

use an array + join:

```
            var sb = [];
            sb.push("<td>...</td>");
            sb.push("<td>...</td>");
            sb.push("</tr>");

            p += sb.join('');
```